# Checksum for Office 365 ProPlus

Tags: office365, checksum

I want to know what is the checksum for Office 365 ProPlus

**Version:** 1701 (Build 7766.2092)

**Channel:** Deferred

---

Example: I want to download notepad++ 64-bit x64

**Link:** https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.4.2/npp.7.4.2.Installer.x64.exe

And they have a checksum list for SHA-1 and MD5

**Link:** https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.4.2/npp.7.4.2.sha1.md5.digest.txt

Comment: Microsoft provides many ways to install or use the same product.
Please let us know the name of ISO-image. This would allow to calculate 
the checksum.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh I will double check on the name of ISO-image. I found this: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/myzXEEwh)

Comment: @AedvaldTseh There is no ISO-image file when I downloaded it. It is just a folder named: Office365-2016. And inside the folder contains a few configuration files and a setup.exe. setup.exe version is 16.0.7614.3602

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it looks like I found it.

As my folder is Office365 2016 Deployment-Tool, thus the folder I downloaded was Office365-2016.

---

Inside the folder contain a setup.exe file which this website have shown it's checksum

**Link:** https://gist.github.com/choco-bot/a5b2481c2fe7b336b1c46cefc87da144

**Hint** (ctrl+f and type checksum)

**Result:** The checksum shows 63AFD1923A1615CF62A00909CEA7AC2E which match my downloaded setup.exe

Lastly, thanks to @AedvaldTseh for your help!